# SQL - transpose a column and grab the value from the adiacent column - wordpress table wp_usermeta

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, pivot, aggregate-functions

I am not too skilled in SQL and Wordpress. I made some form on wordpress and when data are added all the value are inserted in this Wordpress table
[image]

the name of the table is wp_usermeta and is composed in this way
umeta_id - user_id - meta_key - meta_value

Now I have copied the table in a new one using this sql code
CREATE TABLE `elaborazione_Meta_User_data` LIKE `wp_usermeta`;
INSERT INTO `elaborazione_Meta_User_data` SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta`

In this way I can do any "modification" without losing data

My goal is to start from this situation

[image: umeta_id - user_id - meta_key - meta_value 1 2 3 4]

To arrive to this situation

[image: ![enter image description here]

I understand that I have to transpose something, but I do now know how to do.

Other info that should help to solve this problem:

1. if there is a way to "identify" the ids of the users in this table maybe should be simple to create the sql code
2. same for meta_key. These should be the new columns
3. the data in the column should be populated by the value in meta_value
4. in case of "same value" the value to be "updateded" and see at the end of the code should e the one that has a higher value in usermeta_ID
5. next time I am going to add all the data in a new table from the beginning to prevent this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pivot with conditional aggregation:

```
select user_id, 
    max(case when meta_key = 'State' then meta_value end) state,
    max(case when meta_key = 'Addresss' then meta_value end) address,
    max(case when meta_key = 'House_address1' then meta_value end) house_address1,
    max(case when meta_key = 'type_house1' then meta_value end) type_house1,
    max(case when meta_key = 'House_address2' then meta_value end) house_address2,
    max(case when meta_key = 'type_house2' then meta_value end) type_house2
from wp_usermeta
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function of mysql to accomplish this. Check out this link for an in depth tutorial on how to use it. https://ubiq.co/database-blog/transpose-rows-columns-dynamically-mysql/